# How to merge changes to both branches

Tags: git, github, merge

Right now I have a `develop` branch, and I create a new branch `feature-keyboard` using `git checkout -b feature-keyboard develop` as a new version. Right now I need to do changes to both branches. What I am doing right now is I do so: `git checkout -b feature-ui-changes develop` and then add some changes commit them. then `git checkout develop` and `git merge --no-ff feature-ui-changes`. But if I do the same first checkout `feature-keyboard` and then merge changes to `feature-ui-changes`. It says conflict. And It's suppose to. But how do I update changes to both `develop` and `feature-keyboard` branches after I do some changes to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself needing to "double commit" numerous changes between two branches, then that is a sign that there is possibly something wrong with your process. Perhaps the code was branched prematurely.

Git has a nice workflow for creating a "topic" branch where you develop something, while keeping up with the changes from that topic's upstream. Namely, you can use `git rebase` to rewrite the branch history, and migrate the changes to a newer version of upstream.

This saves you the pain of doing double commits, and also prevents you from forking two copies of each upstream commit.

```
$ git checkout -b topic
# ... hack, commit, hack, commit, ...
$ git checkout master
# ... pull, hack, commit, pull, ...
```

Now there is all kinds of new stuff on `master` not reflected in `topic`: changes you have made, plus possibly upstream changes pulled in from another repo. You'd like to return to the work on `topic`, but have that work **based** on the new `master`. That's what **rebasing** is about:

```
$ git checkout topic
$ git rebase master
```

Git will figure out the ancestor point between the current branch, `topic`, and `master`. It will take the `topic` changes from that point, and cherry pick them on top of the current `master`. The resulting picks will then be installed as the `topic` branch. Thereby, the `topic` branch is rewritten: it is replaced with a whole new version of that branch. (Along the way, you may have to resolve conflicts, of course.)

If you have two or more such topics, you can treat them independently: rebase each one of them as you return to it, keeping it up to date with the master changes.

The nice thing after rebasing is that after `topic` is rebased, it contains the upstream branch (such as `master`) as a suffix: it has exactly all the commits that are in `master`, plus some new commits. At that point, you can do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard topic   # fast-forward master to the topic
```

Now `master` has all the `topic` changes: in fact, `master` and `topic` point to the same commit object: they are identical. We can do this safely because `master` doesn't have any commits which are not already in `topic`, thanks to the recent rebase. So we are not throwing away anything from `master`: it just jumps forward.

If `master` does have some new commits, you can also do an "other-way rebase":

```
# on master
git rebase topic   # same as git reset --hard topic if master has no new commits!
```

The new changes on `master` are rewound, then the `topic` changes are brought in, and the new changes are re-played (cherry picked) on top. It's a mirror image of rebasing `topic` to `master`: `rebase` doesn't care which branch is the trunk and which is the topic.

However, if those new `master` commits are public, you are writing public history by rebasing them over `topic` changes. You can get away with this if all the new `master` commits not on `topic` are your own and unpublished (you made them locally and haven't `git push`-ed them to another repo), or you have some other justification for rewriting `master` history even if it is published.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the changes on one branch, commit them. Then switch to the other branch and cherry-pick your changes:

`git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`